# difference between qemu-kvm?

Tags: centos, qemu, kvm

what is different between the following type i get qemu-kvm ? boths are use centos 6.4.

1. yum install qemu-kvm ,then show the version:

   [root@centos6 qemu-kvm]# /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 --version

   QEMU emulator version 1.2.50 (qemu-kvm-devel), Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
2. get the source code and build it by gcc.

   [root@centos6 qemu-kvm]# /usr/libexec/qemu-kvm --version
    QEMU PC emulator version 0.12.1 (qemu-kvm-0.12.1.2), Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard

Answer (score 3):

Qemu uses 2 kinds of cpu virtualization, TCG (tiny code generator) and KVM. TCG emulates all instruction of guest code with plain c code, it translates guest code to host code in real-time. While KVM lets the host directly runs guest code, KVM requires the guest and the host to have the same instruction set (basically, the same cpu), not every cpu can do this, for intel cpus, it requires VMX feature. Which I assume you have understood these.

Qemu-kvm is obsolete, KVM comes with QEMU now if you download the latest code, you just have to compile it with "--enable-kvm" option. Your QEMU source code is very old, the latest version of QEMU is AFAIK, 1.7.

Your yum source provide 1.2.50 version of qemu. Try "yum install qemu", and try running with -enable-kvm if you don't want to build from source code (I haven't tried though)..

Answer (score 1):

Qemu is Hypervisor.
KVM isn't. It is an accelerator(linux module which does the code translation fast) and used with Qemu, because Qemu when used with TCG is slow.